# How get first two only word from string and replace whitespace by underscore (_)

Tags: php, regex

here is the case, I had a string variable contains a fullname with title. I wanna get the name only, without the coma and the title. Then I replace the white space result with underscore (_).

what I've tried :

```php
$name = 'John Doe, Ph.D'
$get_name = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $name, 2);
$username = strtolower($get_name[0] . '_' . $get_name[1]);

dd($get_name, $username); //result : john_doe, ph.d
```

How to get the result like : `john_doe` from the variable `$name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` to first replace remove everything after the second name (if present) to the end and then replace white-space with `_` , passing the lower-cased input to it. This allows you to support input such as `'Fred , M.Sc'` and `'Fred John Doe , B.A'` as well:

```php
$name = 'John Doe, Ph.D';
$get_name = preg_replace(array('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?).*$/', '/\s+/'), array('$1', '_'), strtolower($name));
echo $get_name;
echo "\n";
$name = 'Fred , M.Sc';
$get_name = preg_replace(array('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?).*$/', '/\s+/'), array('$1', '_'), strtolower($name));
echo $get_name;
echo "\n";
$name = 'Fred John Doe , B.A';
$get_name = preg_replace(array('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?).*$/', '/\s+/'), array('$1', '_'), strtolower($name));
echo $get_name;
echo "\n";
$name = 'John Doe';
$get_name = preg_replace(array('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?).*$/', '/\s+/'), array('$1', '_'), strtolower($name));
echo $get_name;
echo "\n";
$name = 'Fred';
$get_name = preg_replace(array('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?).*$/', '/\s+/'), array('$1', '_'), strtolower($name));
echo $get_name;
```

Output:

```
john_doe
fred
fred_john
john_doe
fred
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i560r)

Comment: It works! thank you.. but what about if I want to only get the first 2 word of the fullname? ex : `$name =  'Fred John Doe, Ph.D' ` then how if I only want to get the result like `fred_john` ?

Comment: @stupirl I've updated the answer so that `'Fred John Doe, Ph.D'` will map to `fred_john`